# Obtain drawable from ?android:attr programatically

Tags: android, android-drawable, attr, android-radiobutton

I want to create RadioButton programatically and set drawable End using resource from `?android:attr`. The equivalent in xml is this:

```
android:drawableEnd="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
```

I have tried using typedValue to retrieve it in activity but always resource not found. This is my code:

```
val tv = TypedValue().also {
    theme.resolveAttribute(com.google.android.material.R.attr.listChoiceIndicatorSingleAnimated, it, true)
}
val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, tv.resourceId)
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: `android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle` is equivalent to `android.R.attr.listChoiceIndicatorSingle`, not the one you have there now, which is from the Material Components library.

Comment: thanks that works, btw i got another problem, When one item is selected, other items got selected randomly. I use this `setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, drawable, null)`

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean, but that doesn't sound like it's due to this particular theme drawable or that setter call.

Comment: okay, thank you for your time. maybe i will create separate post for that